# How to set up Stripe Plan to bill quarterly using Stripe.Net

Tags: asp.net, stripe-payments, stripe.net

I am attempting to set up a plan using Stripe.Net that bills quarterly, but I am afraid that it may not be possible out of the box.

Here is my code so far, taken almost directly from the Stripe.Net setup guide:

```
var myPlan = new StripePlanCreateOptions();
myPlan.Amount = 1000;           // all amounts on Stripe are in cents, pence, etc
myPlan.Currency = "usd";        // "usd" only supported right now
myPlan.Interval = "month";      // "month" or "year"
myPlan.IntervalCount = 1;       // optional
myPlan.Name = "Bronze";
myPlan.Id = "Bronze" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
myPlan.TrialPeriodDays = 30;    // amount of time that will lapse before the customer is billed

var planService = new StripePlanService();
StripePlan response = planService.Create(myPlan);
```

I was hoping I could just change the Interval to something like "quarter", but I get the StripeException: Invalid interval: must be one of day, month, week, or year.

This message is quite explicit in that it doesn't expect anything besides day, month, week, or year, but I guess I'm asking if anyone knows a way around this.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: I think you have to take there git code and edit it according to your quarterly requirement..

Comment: Thanks loop, I'd rather not get into altering the Stripe code base if possible but I'll definitely keep that in mind as an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quarter is just another way of saying 3 months, so you can set up a quarterly plan by setting the Interval to `month`, and the IntervalCount to 3.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I wasn't sure if a quarter was a relative term. If it is, then it'll be easy enough to address!

Comment: when pass "interval_count" => 3  
Invalid interval: must be one of month, year, week, or day